Keras Masking Layer for Both Input and Output Layer
I have a tensor with this shape:
(num of samples, num of timesteps, num of features) -> 1000, 60, 4

The first 59 nodes are input for the model, while the last nodes are output for the model at 'axis=1.`
X = tensor.copy()
y = tensor.copy()

X[:, :-1, :] = 0.
y[:, -1:, :] = 0.

So the data would look like this:
X: 1,2,3,4,5,...,0.
y: 0.,0.,0.,0.,...,60

In Keras 3 documents, it's just explaining for model input:
from keras.api.layers, Masking, LSTM, Input

input_layer = Input((60, 4))

hidden_layer = Masking(mask_value=0.)(input_layer)
hidden_layer = LSTM(...)(hidden_layer )
...

Is putting the Masking layer work at the output layer?
...
output_layer = Masking(mask_value=0.)(hidden_layer)

Model(...


It sure "works", but it won't do much. The Masking layer does 2 things: 1: setting values in timesteps with all mask_value to 0's (if mask_value is 0, this does nothing). 2: setting a _keras_mask boolean mask as property to signal following reccurent layers which timesteps to skip. In your example, Masking the output with mask_value=0. does not change any values, as the 0's get replaces by 0's and there are no following layers that use the _keras_mask to skip timesteps.
